# Checking for DB2 Connection before running next SQL script

Tags: sql, batch-file, db2

I want to check to see if there is a DB2 connection before running a SQL file.

To explain:

```
@echo off
if "%DB2CLP%" == "" db2cmd /c /i /w "%0" %* & goto :eof
SET DB2CLP=**$$**
db2 -x connect to XXXXX user XXXXXXXX USING XXXXXXXX
db2 -x set current schema='XXXXXXXX'
db2 -tvsmf query1.sql
db2 -tvsmf query2.sql
db2 -tvsmf query3.sql
```

I need a way of checking before running each of the three queries if the is a database connection present and if not to run the log in script again.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget that women code as well. You can highlight your code and click the `{}` button to mark it up. Why do you need to do this at all? This feels like you're treating a symptom rather than the root cause. If your connection is being dropped wouldn't fixing that be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue the `connect` command without parameters and check the return code; the DB2 CLP returns 4 if an error has occurred.

```
db2 connect >nul
if errorlevel 0 goto :label1
db2 connect to XXX...
:label 1
db2 -tf query1.sql
```

However, keep in mind that this is not guaranteed to work in all cases. For example, if the network connectivity has been disrupted the database connection will remain in a valid state until you issue the next SQL statement, at which point the error will be returned. For this reason you may want to choose running some query that's guaranteed to work, instead of the `connect` command, to "ping" the database server:

```
db2 select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 >nul
if errorlevel 0 goto :label1
db2 connect to XXX...
:label 1
db2 -tf query1.sql
```